# SQLiteDatabase Column does not exist

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQliteDatabase with a column named "MINIATURA" where there is the path of a miniature to set in the listview. If open the database I can see the column with the paths inside, but if I call it in the Cursor adapter it give me error

```
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357): Process: info.androidhive.tabsswipe, PID: 17357
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'MINIATURA' does not exist
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:81)
02-20 13:06:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(17357):    at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.WeedCursorAdapter.<init>(WeedCursorAdapter.java:26)
```

and this is my cursor adapter

```
public class WeedCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    static RegistrationOpenHelperW database_ob;
    RegistrationAdapterW adapter_db;




static String[] from = { database_ob.NAME , database_ob.MIN};
static int[] to = { R.id.tv_fnamew, R.id.img_row_w};

    public WeedCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)
    {
            super(context, R.layout.row_w, c, from, to );
            this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
            ImageView img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_row_w);
            Picasso.with(context)
            .load("file://" + cursor.getString(6))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            //.resizeDimen(R.dimen.miniature_size, R.dimen.miniature_size)
            .into(img1);
    }
}
```

If I change database_ob.MIN in another column it works.
What I made wrong?

EDIT: This is how I create the database

```
public class RegistrationOpenHelperW extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WEED_DB";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "WEED_TABLE";
 public static final int VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String NAME = "NOME";
 public final static String CFS = "COFFEESHOP";
 public static final String DESC = "DESCRIZIONE";
 public static final String IMG1 = "IMG1";
 public static final String IMG2 = "IMG2";
 public static final String MIN = "MINIATURA";
 public static final String SCRIPT = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
           + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME
           + " text not null, " + CFS + " text not null, " + DESC + " text not null," 
           + IMG1 + " text not null," + MIN + " text not null," + IMG2 + " text not null );";
 public RegistrationOpenHelperW(Context context, String name,
           CursorFactory factory, int version) {
          super(context, name, factory, version);
 }
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
 }
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE_NAME);
  onCreate(db);
 }
}
```

this is the database https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Z1A.jpg

Comment: Show the string you used to create your database

Answer (score 0):

Grab the DB and visualise it in an sqlite manager.

I can see that your version is still 1. Maybe you were editing it without the MINIATURA column and the DB currently on the device does not have it.

Maybe if you change the version to 2, so it will upgrade the DB to the latest version could fix the problem?

Comment: I guess you're right. The OP didn't check it in an SQLite manager.

Comment: Was typing the same thing.Had this same problem once, all i did was delete the database and created it again.

Comment: You dont need to delete the DB, just add and handle correctly the DB version migrations

Comment: @BarbeIo  deleted the app data, disinstalled the app, changed version but still get me error

Comment: Well, as it is, it works fine on me. How do you open the DB? How do you instantiate the Cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the database and create it again.Am sure you are viewing an old copy which doesn't have the column.

Comment: I deleted the app data, disinstalled the app, changed version but still get me error

Comment: If you delete, you don't need to change the version

Comment: This could be commented

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you change the name of column 
"**MINIATURE**" to  "**MINIATURA**" :)

so database already created column "**MINIATURE**" so your name "**MINIATURA**" is not finding,

solution is simple just uninstall app and install fresh one or increase db  version.

hope this will help you.